# Updating a data attribute from a changed prop in a VueJS component that extends another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a VueJS component which needs to update a data attributes when a prop updates.

The component extends an autocomplete component that requires a `query` data attribute. However, it's not working as I am expecting.

How can I update the `query` data attribute when the `values` prop updates?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input :name="fieldName" type="hidden" v-bind:value="values.id">

        <input :name="'search[' + fieldName + ']'"
               type="text"
               v-model="query"
               @keydown.down="down"
               @keydown.up="up"
               @keydown.enter.prevent
               @keydown.enter="hit"
               @keydown.esc="reset"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import VueTypeahead from 'vue-typeahead'

    export default {
        extends: VueTypeahead,

        props: ['endpoint', 'fieldName', 'values', 'format'],

        data () {
            return {
                query: '',
                src: this.endpoint,
                limit: 5,
                minChars: 3,
                queryParamName: 'q'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't this basically the same question asked earlier today? https://stackoverflow.com/q/44570949/38065

Comment: @BertEvans ha! well, I realised afterwards that you answered my question but the question wasn't quite what I needed. This was about watching the prop (which I didn't know/think about). Maybe if I knew a bit more about Vue I could/should have worked this out!

Comment: It's all good, I was just curious why they were so similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a watcher on `values` and update the `query` in that:

```
watch: {
  values() { // called anytime this.values changes
    this.query = this.values;
  }
}
```

Comment: Dude, you have saved the day! Thank you. I have been trying to solve this all afternoon and got to the point where I couldn't see the wood for the trees!